# retrieve the ids of an array

Tags: angular

When I do a :

```
console.log(this.productService.getSortedProduct(graphicData)['finalProductList'])
```

I get this:

```
0: []
1: []
2: []
3: []
4: []
5: []
6: []
7: Array(2)
   0: {products_id: 1039992, date: "2020-08-20"}
   1: {products_id: 1039997, date: "2020-08-20"}
8: []
9: []
10: []
11: []
12: Array(2)
   0: {products_id: 1039995, date: "2020-08-20"}
   1: {products_id: 1039996, date: "2020-08-20"}
```

How to retrieve all values of products_Id from tables?

I see on google, i need to be a méthod for ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by iterating over the array. If the element has values then retrieve its elements else skip iteration over it.

Please find below working logic using simple `for` loop:

```js
const arr = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [{
      products_id: 1039992,
      date: "2020-08-20"
    },
    {
      products_id: 1039997,
      date: "2020-08-20"
    },
  ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [{
      products_id: 1039995,
      date: "2020-08-20"
    },
    {
      products_id: 1039996,
      date: "2020-08-20"
    }
  ]
];

let result = [];

for (const item of arr) {
  if (item.length) {
    result = [...result, ...item.map(value => value.products_id)];
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much